# Error while Scilab module is loading

Tags: scilab

I downloaded module Metanet 0.6.2 and ran by Scilab

```
atomsInstall
```

After that i ran

```
`atomsLoad('metanet')`
```

but it shows

> atomsLoad: An error occurred while loading 'metanet-0.6.2':
>           error(msprintf(gettext('%s module required."),'graph'));
>                                                      ^^
>
> Error: Heterogeneous string detected, starting with ' and ending with ".
>   at line   335 of function atomsLoad ( D:\Program Files\scilab-6.0.1\modules\atoms\macros\atomsLoad.sci line 351 )

Why did it happen so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the metanet module is not supported by Scilab 6.0.1 yet. I had to install version 5.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, both the question and the accepted answer here on this page are very vague and misleading. Ideally, this kind of post should be blocked / down-voted, but I will try to answer it as much as I can.

Firstly when you want to run a Scilab command you do not put it in quotation marks, unless you want to use `execstr` command. However, the characters you have used are not quotations but backticks! I'm not sure why you have done that.

Secondly, the error:

> Error: Heterogeneous string detected, starting with ' and ending with "

happens when a double quotation is used inside the single quotation or vice versa:

```
"This is a' string"
'this is a" string'
```

to solve the issue you should change the above strings to

```
"This is a'' string"
'this is a'" string'
```

basically adding one single quotation before any of the `'` and `"` characters to turn them into literal `'` and `"`.

bonus point if you want to pass a string to Tcl use curly brackets

```
TCL_EvalStr("set myVar {Hello World!}")
```

or

```
TCL_EvalStr("set myVar '"Hello World!'"")
```

but for PowerShell

```
powershell('$myVar= ''Hello World!''')
```

or

```
powershell("$myVar= ''Hello World!''")
```